# How to invoke AWS lambda function over http from IoT device?

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, iot

The device doesnt support https requests so I need to make http request to a lambda function from a device and pass some data as well. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use API Gateway to create an endpoint connected to the Lambda function you built.